# HTML-How To Set onclick to be AutoClick

Tags: html

hey,
I'm trying to set an html file to click automaticaly on Login Button.
How Can I do it. 
I try : onclick="window.open(this.href,'_self')". it dosen't work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083084/automating-web-activity-which-includes-form-submission-javascript-and-ssl

Comment: or here: http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/.  I don't think you can do it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to trigger a click when the page loads you could use:

```
onLoad="window.open(this.href,'_self')"
```

Comment: I see, using jquery it is very simple:
$('#idOfButton').trigger('click');